# speed up symbolic summation

Tags: performance-tuning, symbolic, summation

I have the following summation

```
 L=24;
 sind=Range[-Pi,Pi,2*Pi/L];
 Sum[f, {x, sind}, {y, sind}, {x1, sind}, {y1, sind}, {x2, sind}, {y2, sind}]
```

where `f` has been evaluated at a previous step and is a function of `x,y,x1,x2,y1,y2`.
However `f` contains symbols, e.g `f= Cos[x]*Sin[y]*Sin[x+x1]*Cos[y+y1]*a[x,y]+g[x,y]*Cos[x2-y2]*Sin[x+x1+x2]`  where `a, g` are abstract functions that don't take explicit real values or symbolic values.
They will stay as `a[-Pi,-Pi] etc` at the end of the calculation.

Is there a way to speed up such sums? They are very slow...

Comment: Your specific example contains a typo (`Sin[x+x1+x2,y+y1+y2]`) and an unknown function (`g[x,y]`).  You're more likely to get answers with a complete specific example.

Comment: @JimB thanks for the comment. Typo corrected. `a`, `g` are symbolic functions. Their explicit form is unimportant. They will stay as `a[-Pi,-Pi], g[-Pi,Pi],...` at the end of the summation.

Comment: Maybe you can write a sum of products as a product of sums? $a_1b_1+a_1b_2+a_2b_1+a_2b_2=(a_1+a_2)(b_1+b_2)$

Answer (score 1):

Instead of evaluating a single sum, you could break up the sum into two or more sums.

```
L = 24;
sind = Range[-Pi, Pi, 2*Pi/L];
a[x_, y_] := x y
g[x_, y_] := x + y
f = Cos[x]*Sin[y]*Sin[x + x1]*Cos[y + y1]*a[x, y] + g[x, y]*Cos[x2 - y2]*Sin[x + x1 + x2];
AbsoluteTiming[sx = Sum[f, {x, sind}, {x1, sind}, {x2, sind}] // Simplify;
 sxy = Sum[sx, {y, sind}, {y1, sind}, {y2, sind}] // Simplify]
(* {1.23668, 625/4 π (52 (2 + Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[6]) + (7 + 4 Sqrt[3]) π)} *)
```

If `a[x,y]` and `g[x,y]` are unknown indexed functions, then still breaking into multiple sums seems feasible:

```
L = 24;
sind = Range[-Pi, Pi, 2*Pi/L];

fa = Cos[x]*Sin[y]*Sin[x + x1]*Cos[y + y1]*a[x, y];
AbsoluteTiming[sax1x2 = Sum[fa, {x1, sind}, {x2, sind}] // Simplify;
 sax1x2y1y2 = Sum[sax1x2, {y1, sind}, {y2, sind}] // Simplify;
 sax1x2y1y2y = Sum[sax1x2y1y2, {y, sind}] // Simplify;
 sa = Sum[sax1x2y1y2y, {x, sind}];]
(* {0.131486, Null} *)

fg = g[x, y]*Cos[x2 - y2]*Sin[x + x1 + x2];
AbsoluteTiming[
 sgx1x2 = Sum[fg, {x1, sind}, {x2, sind}] // Simplify;
 sgx1x2y1y2 = Sum[sgx1x2, {y1, sind}, {y2, sind}] // Simplify;
 sgx1x2y1y2y = Sum[sgx1x2y1y2, {y, sind}] // Simplify;
 sg = Sum[sgx1x2y1y2y, {x, sind}];]
(* {0.13079, Null} *)
```

And one can certainly speed things up a bit more with `fa` and `fg` by noticing that `x2` and `y2` are not in `fa` and `y1` is not in `fg`.

Comment: If `a`, `g` had explicit forms that would work (along with other solutions). I am mentioning that `a`, `g` are symbolic functions that will stay as `a[-Pi,Pi] etc`

Comment: I might be wrong but I think you mean "indexed function" rather than "symbolic function" as `g[x_,y_]:=a+b y+c x` is also a symbolic function.